# Getting connection closed error when trying to read response from FitNesse REST URI

Tags: c#, .net, rest, fitnesse

Have you run into this problem? I run code remarkably similar to that from a [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614458/parse-fitnesse-restful-xml-output-into-tfs-test-format), When in nUnitTest mode and the URI includes "/?test&format=xml" the nUnit test fails with and IOException, "Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection is closed."

However the Fiddler trace that was running at the time shows the very xml I expected.

I've recreated the request headers exactly (almost) as they are sent when sent through the browser.

Finally, if I leave off the "/?test&format=xml" from the URI, I get the html I would have otherwise expected.

SOURCE CODE:

```
    public virtual bool Run()
    {
        var request = CreateRequest();
        var response = GetResponse(request);
        var responseString = ReadResponse(response);
        this.SetResults(responseString);
        return this.IsSuccessful;
    }

    protected internal virtual HttpWebRequest CreateRequest()
    {
        var address = TestConfig.Address;

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);

        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);

        return request;
    }

    protected internal virtual HttpWebResponse GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

        return response;
    }

    protected internal virtual string ReadResponse(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var responseString = ReadResponse(stream);

        stream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return responseString;
    }

    protected internal virtual string ReadResponse(Stream stream)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return responseString;
    }
```

Comment: I'm intrigued.  Source code, please.  :-)

Comment: Added the source code...

Comment: Does the content-length header sent by the server match the actual length of the content?

Comment: No, the content-length header returned is -1. However when I inspect the response with Fiddler, there is actual content in the response body.

Comment: Maybe setting request.KeepAlive=false would help...

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection is closed." doesn't really tie up with the fact you're seeing Fiddler getting a html response body back.

Check the StatusCode of the HttpWebResponse (should be 200 if ok), also wrap the request in try/catch block (example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode(v=vs.80).aspx)

```
try 
   {    
        // Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL. 
        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
        // Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(); 
        if (myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
           Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Status Code is OK and StatusDescription is: {0}",
                                myHttpWebResponse.StatusDescription);
        // Releases the resources of the response.
        myHttpWebResponse.Close(); 

    } 
catch(WebException e) 
   {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nWebException Raised. The following error occured : {0}",e.Status); 
   }
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe following Exception was raised : {0}",e.Message);
}
```

If you're creating and disposing of the HttpWebRequest object quickly you might be getting the socket going into a time_wait state as it is shutting down, then you can't re-open it again until it has completely closed. If this is the case, look into using another port or changing the time the connection lives for.