# Parsing XML results into cc.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, fitnesse

I have used the parser in thread

[Parse Fitnesse RESTFul XML output into TFS Test format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614458/parse-fitnesse-restful-xml-output-into-tfs-test-format)

And I get the result in XML as I want.

I want to 
1: include the running of this parsing in MSBuild as a Target and I think I am almost there, with a Exec target
2: show the results of the testrunning in cc.net. Anyone who knows how to do that? It inludes parsing the XML into something cc.net can interpret.

Thank You,

Magnus

Answer (score 0):

CruiseControl.net already has [an xsl](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+FitNesse) for displaying Fitnesse results.  You shouldn't need to parse anything.

Comment: do you happend to know in what format the xml that fitnesse.xsl in ccnet should interpret should be? I made it all work but it seems like my xml file wich I manage to include in the buiild log is on a different format than fitnesse.xsl can interpret. Maybe U got an example file you could paste in?

Magnus

Comment: I don't know what the default output for fitnesse looks like, but I would have assumed that it would work with the xsl provided in ccnet.  If you are trying to use xml you parsed yourself, you will need to modify the xsl to match your new format.

Answer (score 0):

In your CCNET project configuration, make sure you merge the XML result file from the Fitneese report.

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/File+Merge+Task

Answer (score 0):

For me it´s working following the instructions given here: http://gojko.net/FitNesse/book/ch10s03.html