# FitNesse integration with CCNet, correct XML in the build log?

Tags: msbuild, dashboard, fitnesse, ccnet-config

I am almost there with my fitnesse to ccnet integration, but my results aren't showing up in my dashboard despite following this:

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+FitNesse

I have merged my xml result file using the File Merge Task, that I generated using this:
[Parse Fitnesse RESTFul XML output into TFS Test format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614458/parse-fitnesse-restful-xml-output-into-tfs-test-format)

In the XML below, is the xml the way it should be? This is my logfile from ccnet webdashboard:

```
<cruisecontrol project="MagnusTest">
<request source="KDP021368" buildCondition="ForceBuild">Build (ForceBuild) triggered    from KDP021368</request>
<parameters>
<parameter name="$CCNetArtifactDirectory" value="C:\Program   Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\MagnusTest\Artifacts" />
<parameter name="$CCNetBuildCondition" value="ForceBuild" />
<parameter name="$CCNetBuildDate" value="2011-05-05" />
<parameter name="$CCNetBuildTime" value="14:36:44" />
<parameter name="$CCNetFailureUsers" value="System.Collections.ArrayList" />
<parameter name="$CCNetIntegrationStatus" value="Unknown" />
<parameter name="$CCNetLabel" value="7" />
<parameter name="$CCNetLastIntegrationStatus" value="Success" />
<parameter name="$CCNetListenerFile" value="C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\MagnusTest\Artifacts\MagnusTest_ListenFile.xml" />
<parameter name="$CCNetModifyingUsers" value="System.Collections.ArrayList" />
<parameter name="$CCNetNumericLabel" value="7" />
<parameter name="$CCNetProject" value="MagnusTest" />
<parameter name="$CCNetProjectUrl" value="http://KDP021368/ccnet" />
<parameter name="$CCNetRequestSource" value="KDP021368" />
<parameter name="$CCNetUser" value="" />
<parameter name="$CCNetWorkingDirectory" value="C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\MagnusTest\WorkingDirectory" />
</parameters>
<modifications />
<integrationProperties>
<CCNetArtifactDirectory>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\MagnusTest\Artifacts</CCNetArtifactDirectory>
<CCNetBuildCondition>ForceBuild</CCNetBuildCondition>
<CCNetBuildDate>2011-05-05</CCNetBuildDate>
<CCNetBuildTime>14:36:44</CCNetBuildTime>
<CCNetFailureUsers />
<CCNetIntegrationStatus>Success</CCNetIntegrationStatus>
<CCNetLabel>7</CCNetLabel>
<CCNetLastIntegrationStatus>Success</CCNetLastIntegrationStatus>
<CCNetListenerFile>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\MagnusTest\Artifacts\MagnusTest_ListenFile.xml</CCNetListenerFile>
<CCNetModifyingUsers />
<CCNetNumericLabel>7</CCNetNumericLabel>
<CCNetProject>MagnusTest</CCNetProject>
<CCNetProjectUrl>http://KDP021368/ccnet</CCNetProjectUrl>
<CCNetRequestSource>KDP021368</CCNetRequestSource>
<CCNetWorkingDirectory>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\MagnusTest\WorkingDirectory</CCNetWorkingDirectory>
<LastIntegrationStatus>Success</LastIntegrationStatus>
<LastSuccessfulIntegrationLabel>7</LastSuccessfulIntegrationLabel>
<LastModificationDate>04.05.2011 14:36:46</LastModificationDate>
</integrationProperties>
<build date="2011-05-05 14:36:44" buildtime="00:00:01" buildcondition="ForceBuild">

<msbuild startTime="05/05/2011 14:36:45" elapsedTime="00:00:01" elapsedSeconds="1" success="true">
<project name="FitnesseTest" file="M:\magnufu_PCtcGbad1_Test\CtcGbad1_pres\BuildAllComponents.proj" startTime="05/05/2011 14:36:46" elapsedTime="00:00:00" elapsedSeconds="0" success="true">
<target name="FitnesseTest" startTime="05/05/2011 14:36:46" elapsedTime="00:00:00" elapsedSeconds="0" success="true">
  <message level="high"><![CDATA[echo Dette er BuildAllComponents.proj]]></message>
  <message level="high"><![CDATA[Dette er BuildAllComponents.proj]]></message>
</target>
</project>
</msbuild>

<SummaryResult>
<TestName>TestSmoke</TestName>
<TestResult>Failed</TestResult>
<ErrorMessage>6 right, 3 wrong, 0 ignores and 2 exceptions.
</ErrorMessage>
<InnerTests>
<InnerTest>
  <TestName>TestSmoke</TestName>
  <TestResult>Failed</TestResult>
  <ErrorMessage>6 right, 3 wrong, 0 ignores and 2 exceptions.
</ErrorMessage>
</InnerTest>
</InnerTests>
</SummaryResult></build>
</cruisecontrol>
```

So why arent my results showing up in the dashboard? I have edited my dashboard.config to include:

```
 <xslReportBuildPlugin description="Fitnesse Report" actionName="FitnesseReport"       xslFileName="xsl\fitnesse.xsl"/>
```

and I get the XML in my build log.

Thank You!

Cheers

Comment: the ccnet webdashbord page did give me an error message at first, not being able to find my xsl, but I solved this and it found it, but the page is loaded and gets blank (with alle the menu elements and so forth).